# Can't load images from assets folder in nested components (Vue.js 2.0 / Webpack)

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm new to webpack and Vue.js. I'm facing issues when trying to load images/videos in my nested components, it gives me "not found" error.
I have project structure like that:

[image: Project structure image]

Let's say in Signup.Vue I want to load an image from the assets folder, how can I do that? 
Because "**.../assets/my-img.jpg**" didn't work out, 
"**assets/my-img.jpg**" neither. In css I figured out that using require with "~" works (ex.   '**~assets/my-img.jpg**" ).
I don't undestand how paths work.

Placing my images in the same component's folder would be an option, but I want to use the main assets folder where I can fetch media from.

Using: webpack 2.7.0 / vue 2.0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require with a tilde(~) works because in the CSS files it resolves the path to your `node_modules` directory and you don't have to set up a relative path.

In your case you are currently in the **signup** directory so you would have to go up 3 directories before you reach the **assets** directory.

So your relative path would become:

`../../../assets/my-img.jpg`

With Webpack you also have the option to resolve straight away to a directory with a resolve alias which might be a prettier option for you:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS/SCSS use as follows:

```css
background: url(../../../assets/logo.png);
```